# Bootstrap - Display more than one modal at the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

During a process with a modal displayed for the loading, another modal could be displayed over the previous one when an error occurs. When I try to test this situation, I have an error message in the log of my browser (Firefox)

```
ERROR too much recursion        jquery.min.js
```

Despite this message, everything is working perfectly (the new modal is diplayed over the first one). The error message does not impact the user (it's not visible) but I'm wondering if I should find a way to correct this problem.

Do we have the right to display more than one modal at the same time with Bootstrap & Jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't. [Read The Fine Documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals):

> ### Overlapping modals not supported
>
> Be sure not to open a modal while another is still visible. Showing more than one modal at a time requires custom code.

Comment: OK it's clear. Sorry I did not read the documentation correctly. Thanks